# How can I detect whether Emacs is running in batch mode?

Tags: emacs, batch-processing

Sometimes I want to run emacs in batch mode, and in such cases I want to avoid doing certain things in my init, such as starting the emacs server. Is there any way to test from within Emacs Lisp whether Emacs is running in batch mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Batch-Mode.html

-- Variable: **noninteractive**

```
This variable is non-nil when Emacs is running in batch mode.
```

Comment: That was it. I knew I remembered some way to do it. Thanks!